Mock helper function in Storybook 8?
I'm working to implement Storybook 8 into my Nuxt 3 application, and am running in to an issue with a component that relies on an imported helper function.
The component I am basing my story off of uses the following function:
export const buildImageSrc = (url: string | undefined | null) => {
  if (!url) return undefined;
  const supabase = useSupabaseClient<Database>();
  const { data } = supabase.storage.from('avatars')
    .getPublicUrl(url);
  return data?.publicUrl ?? undefined;
};

As you can see, it utilizes Supabase to return a public url of the user's avatar. The story builds and returns this error though:
Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'supabase.storage')

Is there a way to mock this function in Storybook?
